# android inflator issue R cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, android-menu

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

i am getting R cannot be resolved to a variable error on this line.

Thanks for your help.enter

Comment: import `yourProject.R` , and if you can't see your `xml` file, you might have an error on one of them

Comment: what? import ? you might have an error on your xml file, check all of your layout, menu's and other xml file

Answer (score 0):

The 99.9% of `R` related errors usually comes due to some typographical (i.e., bad syntax) problem within any layout you have in your project.

The other 0.1% comes from a typographical problem within your Manifest file.

So you'll have to look at each of your layout files consciously and see which ones has the bad structure/syntax.

Comment: can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: There's no much more on what elaborate, since you've not posted your layouts. You have some syntax error in one of them and your framework is not showing it to you, so you have to find it by yourself examining all your .xml layout files to determine which is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues, rebuilding using build>make project did the trick for me.